# How to plot population growth model?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, ecology

How would I draw the graph of a function $\frac{dy}{dt}=(Ry^2/T)-Ry$ in *Mathematica*?

I have tried a few times but the constants are confusing me.

Comment: See the first example in tutorial [Nonlinear IVP and BVPs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/DSolveNonlinearBVPs.html)

Comment: You might realize this already, but this isn't a standard population model like the logistic unless you take $R<0$.

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the arbitrary constant of integration by imposing an initial condition.

```
dfeq = {y'[t] == R (y[t]^2/T - y[t]), y[0] == 1};
First@DSolve[dfeq, y[t], t]
```

> `{y[t] -> T/(1 - E^(R t) + E^(R t) T)}`

```
Manipulate[
   Plot[T/(1 - E^(R t) + E^(R t) T), {t, -1., 1.}, 
        Exclusions -> (-E^(R t) + E^(R t) T == -1)],
   {{R, -1.2}, -2, 2}, 
   {{T, 0.3}, -1, 1}]
```

[image: manipulation ui for plot]